# Jasmine, mock `new Audio()` class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I have the following method

```
  playSound(): void {
    const audio = new Audio(`/assets/speeches/${this.code}.mp3`);
    audio.play().then();
  }
```

I want to write test for `audio.play().then();` but I cannot spy upon `new Audio()`. What I have tried is `spyOn(global, 'Audio');` which has not worked for me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: do you mean `window`?

Comment: Do you mean spyOn(window, 'Audio') ?

Comment: yes please try that.

Comment: Yeah that works, thanks man. If you dont mind please post your answer then I can close the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`global` isn't the global context for a browser. Use `window` instead.

```
spyOn(window, 'Audio');
```